# Show random products via php excluding one category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

In WooCommerce, I'm using a script to show a number of random products but now I need to exclude one product category which I don't need to appear in this section.

How this can be done in my code?

My code:

```
<?php
    global $product; 
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 4,
        'orderby'          => 'rand',
        'post_type'        => 'product' 
    );
    $random_products = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ( $random_products as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <li class="single_product_lower_widget" style="list-style:none;">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <span class="single_product_lower_widget_image">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>
            <span class="product-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
            </span>
            <p><?php get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_price', true ); ?></p>
        </a>
        </li>
    <?php 
    endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a **`'tax_query'`** (defining the unwanted product category) this way:

```
<?php
    // Set HERE your product category (to be excluded)
    $category_slug = 'music' ;
    $random_products = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 4,
        'orderby'          => 'rand',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'post_type'        => 'product',
        'tax_query' => array( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $category_slug,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ))
    ));

    foreach ( $random_products as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
?>
    <li class="single_product_lower_widget" style="list-style:none;">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <span class="single_product_lower_widget_image">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>
            <span class="product-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
            </span>
            <p><?php get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_price', true ); ?></p>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php
    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Tested and works

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Set HERE your product category (to be excluded)
$category_slug = 'music' ;
$random_products = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 4,
    'orderby'          => 'rand',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'post_type'        => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $category_slug,
        'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    ))
));

foreach ( $random_products as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
 ?>
<li class="single_product_lower_widget" style="list-style:none;">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <span class="single_product_lower_widget_image">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>
        <span class="product-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
        </span>
        <p><?php get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_price', true ); ?></p>
    </a>
</li>
<?php
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
 ?>
```